# How to run gradle tests parallel on CircleCI?

Tags: gradle, circleci

How can I use CircleCI parallelism to run parallel gradle tests? I have a project with multiple modules, I want CircleCI to run modules one different processors. Currently, it runs all tests on all processors when I specify parallelism.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a bash script that runs tests for appropriate modules using the CircleCI node number.